# Firebase - Retrieve all data from child where key contains VAR

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

**Working with Android and FireBase, and stumpled upon a problem, from what we wanna achieve**

We have a document where the key is 2 names like Bob_Jimmy

Every Name is Unique, but can appear in different setups like:
Bob_Jimmy
Jimmy_Bob
Bob_Carl

Since this is the key, how should/would you go about getting data from all the keys where 'Bob' is part of the key? since we only know Bob

Answer (score 0):

Create Firebase database reference and in onDataChange() method check wether the key contains your variable. For example:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
     if(dataSnapshot.getKey().contains("bob")){
             {your code}
       }
  }

 });
```

if I have your youe database structure i may be able to write accurate code. This is just a sample.
You can use addChildEventListener() if u want to listen to new child adding events.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Realtime Database Query class to retrieve data sorted by key, by value, or by value of a child. You can also filter the sorted result to a specific number of results or a range of keys or values

> Note: Filtering and sorting can be expensive, especially when done on
>   the client. If your app uses queries, define the .`indexOn` rule to
>   index those keys on the server and improve query performance as
>   described in Indexing Your Data.

You can [sort data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) using following methods

> Method    Usage

**orderByChild()**  Order results by the value of a specified child key.

**orderByKey()**    Order results by child keys.

**orderByValue()**  Order results by child values

**startAt()**   Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

**endAt()** Return items less than or equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

**equalTo()**   Return items equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

Comment: These all information given in Firebase documentation. Give specific answer related to question asked. Not need to **COPY - PASTE** documentation here.